# Do I need the Mageplaza Layered Navigation and Search extensions?

Tags: category, error, layered-navigation, mageplaza

```
Magento 2.4.2-p1
Smartwave Porto theme
17 Amasty extensions
ShopperApproved app/software
```

I have these 2 extensions in my Magento and I have no idea where they came from? Either they were there in the default set up or Amasty possibly added them? I've asked Amasty but no answer yet.

The problem is - these 2 Mageplaza extensions:

- Mageplaza Layered Navigation
- Mageplaza Search

seem to be creating problems now = there is an Error now anytime someone tries to click on any category or do any Search as described in my post here:

[ShopperApproved installed their extension and now all categories will not load](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/371217/shopperapproved-installed-their-extension-and-now-all-categories-will-not-load)

Both of these Mageplaza extensions were disabled to begin with. I tried turning them ON and OFF again but the problem remains. **Is it safe to uninstall the extensions?**

Answer (score 0):

Mageplaza Layered Navigation and Mageplaza Search extensions are bundled in the Porto theme. However, the Porto theme doesn't require these extensions to function. Therefore, if you wish to remove them, you can safely do so.

If you decide to remove the Mageplaza Layered Navigation extension, make sure to also remove the Mageplaza Ajax Layer (`Mageplaza_AjaxLayer`) extension if it is installed on your site.